# C Passing data/structure to another function and returning reference on structure

Tags: c

1. How do I return reference on type TITLE* and LEN* in functions
2. How do I pass filled structure from one function to another (through main)

Program example (only example not working as I wat it ):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
TITLE *part_struct(char *line);
LEN *lenght(TITLE *title);

int main(){
      char line[]="Thomas,Bukurest";
      part_struct(line);      //this function must return reference on type TITLE*
      //when is structure filled with data I need to pass them to another function
      lenght(title);     //this does not compile and should return reference on type LEN*
      return 0;
}

typedef struct title {
      char* city;
      char* name;
}TITLE;

typedef struct len {
      int x;
      int y;
}LEN;      



TITLE *part_struct(char *line){           //this line must stay as it is
      TITLE *title = (TITLE*)malloc(sizeof(TITLE));
      char* buffer;
      char copy[20];
      strcpy(copy,line);
      buffer = strtok (copy,",");
      title->name=(char*) malloc(sizeof (char)*(strlen(buffer)));
      title->name=buffer;
      buffer = strtok (NULL, ",");
      title->city=(char*) malloc(sizeof (char)*(strlen(buffer)));
      title->city=buffer;
      return level;  //I am not sure if I am returning it as reference on type TITLE*
}



LEN *lenght(TITLE *title){     //this line must stay as it is
      LEN *len = (LEN*)malloc(sizeof(LEN));
      len->x=strlen(level->name);
      len->y=strlen(level->city);
      return len;
}
```

Comment: You haven't declared anything called `level` inside `part_struct` function; rather have an unused variable called `title`. You miss a semicolon after the `typedef struct len { ... } LEN`. Then you are trying to use the functions `part_struct` and `length` inside `main`, before having them either declared or prototyped. You also are attempting to pass an argument called `title` to the function `length`, which also is not known to the `main` by that time. All in all, amount of mistakes there is just scary.

Comment: Why are you mentioning references? There are no references in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do I return reference on type TITLE* and LEN* in functions.

```
TITLE *part_struct(char *line) {           //this line must stay as it is
   TITLE *title = (TITLE*)malloc(sizeof(TITLE));
   ...

   return(title);
   }

LEN *lenght(TITLE *title){     //this line must stay as it is
   LEN *len = (LEN*)malloc(sizeof(LEN));
   ...

   return(len);
   }
```

How do I pass filled structure from one function to another (through main)

```
int main(){
   char line[]="Thomas,Bukurest";
   TITLE *title = NULL;
   LEN   *len = NULL;

   title=part_struct(line);      //this function must return reference on type TITLE*
   //when is structure filled with data I need to pass them to another function
   len = lenght(title); //does not compile and should return reference on type LEN*
   return 0;   
}
```